# Is it bad to have many classes in a HTML element?

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering

In modern HTML coding, it is popular to add several class names to an element such as

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4 ..."
</div>
```

This gives us a great flexibility for mixing CSS properties without repeating them for different classes.

Logically, the browsers consumes more resources to collect CSS properties of different classes for applying to the corresponding element.

Since it is difficult to run a reliable benchmark on this, I am asking this question from theoretical point of view. Imagine that most of the HTML elements of a page have several classes (e.g. 10 classes). Does this make the page render more difficult and slower? Is this slowdown sensible and considerable?

In general, what is the common process of browsers to read properties from different classes?

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm

Comment: @Morpheus this links introduce the general possibility (in fact what I quoted in the question too). There is no comment on performance of browser rendering.

Comment: Is there a reason to expect that the number of classes would have any perceivable effect, given the speed of modern computers and all the features on web pages that may *really* make them slow? The question sounds speculative, and without a good reason to speculate.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela This is indeed my question. Is this slowdown noticeable? Sometimes we think that a rendering issue is not really noticeable but in complicated cases, they are real problems.

Comment: I think that, theoretically, there will be a definite slowdown on rendering. However, as @JukkaK.Korpela said, modern computers and browsers are so fast that it can be neglected. Also, keep in mind that when the page loads, the entire CSS-file is loaded aswell. In the end there might be a slowdown of somewhat 0,2 to 0,5 seconds I reckon.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts we have modern powerful computers, but users also become more active. These days, most of users tend to open many pages together through browser tabs. Thus, the sum of such slowdowns can be considerable for the end user. Therefore, it is not bad to consider such possible drawbacks.

Comment: Whatever the performance drawbacks are, I think OOCSS is the way to go. Just like OOP, the code itself may be lengthy or have a lot of small classes or w.e, one of the advantages is loosely coupled code. Think of inheritance vs composition. With composition, I can easily add styles or adjust if it's slightly different or add additional styles to the 'toolbox' to use if none are suitable. Whereas when you see stuff like descendant selectors or few big classes encompassing multiple styles, it's hard to reuse them and can't change them without affecting something else.

Answer (score 1):

The interest in adding many classes, is to have separate classes for individual styles and not repeat/create a new class for the same use.

For instance, if I have a button, I can have 3 classes, like `.btn .big .grey`. If I want to create another button, I only need to repeat the .btn class, and add my other custom classes, like `.medium`, and `.green`. It's called the OOCSS (Oriented Object CSS).

With regard to performance, I recommend you watch this little example http://www.css-101.org/descendant-selector/go_fetch_yourself.php, http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors and you can find a lot of articles about performance on ids vs classes.

Comment: Your links are related to CSS selectors and how `descendant selectors` can affect the performance. My question is about `individual classes`.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple classes can make it easier to add special effects to elements without having to create a whole new style for that element. For example, you may want to have the ability to float elements to the left or right quickly. You might write two classes "left" and "right" with just "float:left;" and "float:right;" in them. Then whenever you had an element you need to float left you would simply add the class "left" to its class list.

I like to use multiple classes for things that I want to keep standard across the entire site. For example, if I always want the bottom-margin for elements that have a bottom-margin to be 10px. By creating a class that only encompases the botom-margin:10px; I can add it wherever it's needed.

Disadvantages of Multiple Classes

While they are supported in the major browsers, really old browsers don't support them. So you should make sure that the first class you list is the one with the most specific information for that element.

Multiple classes can also get really confusing as you apply more and more to an element.

[More...](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm)

Summary:

- Reduce total number of selectors (including IE-related styles: .ie7
  .foo .bar)
- Avoid universal selectors (including unqualified attribute selectors:
  [type="url"])
- Page zoom affects CSS performance in some browsers (e.g. Opera)
- Window size affects CSS performance in some browsers (e.g. Chrome)
- Page reloads can negatively affect CSS performance in some browsers
  (e.g. Opera)
- “border-radius” and “transform” are among most expensive properties
  (in at least WebKit & Opera)
- “Timeline” tab in WebKit-based browsers can shed light on total
  recalc/reflow/repaint times
- Selector matching is much faster in WebKit

http://perfectionkills.com/